# Chaining constructor with const char * as argument gives unexpected results

Tags: c++, string

I have this C++ class:

```
class Test
{
private:
    string _string;

public:
    Test()
    {

    }
    Test(const char *s)
    {
        Test((string)s);
    }
    Test(string s)
    {
        _string = s;
    }
    operator const char *()
    {
        return _string.c_str();
    }
    operator string()
    {
        return _string;
    }
};
```

If I use this code in `main` "1234" is printed to the console:

```
int main()
{
    Test test = string("1234");
    string s = test;

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But with this, nothing is printed:

```
int main()
{
    Test test = "1234";   // Only change
    string s = test;

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is which constructor is called. It apperas that the `_string` variable is a default string instance with the value "" but I don't see how that could have happend. I thought that since `_string` is on the stack, the assignment I do is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Test(const char *s)
{
    Test((string)s);
}
```

does not chain the constructors. It just creates a temporary object in the body of the function. What you need is:

```
Test(const char *s) : Test(string(s)) 
{
}
```

Comment: As a note, this functionality is also only present in C++11 and above; previous versions of the standard did not allow delegating constructors.

Comment: @user3956212: Aside from that, why not simply rely on implicit conversions?

Comment: I actually don't know, I guess I just didn't want to rely on implicit conversions.